# How to keep certain values in an ArrayList and remove the rest?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

My ArrayList is called `values` and I can remove strings using the code below. The ArrayList has strings, negative values and other integers which I would like to delete but I can't use the remove method for it as I don't know all the values. This makes it impossible for me to use code below. I want to keep all values between 1 to 23 and delete the rest.

```
values.remove("O9N");
```

I tried using this method but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone have a look at it and tell me where i am going wrong.

```
int col = 2; 
List values = new ArrayList(table.getRowCount());

for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
values.add(table.getValueAt(row, col));
}

List<String> thingsIWantToKeep = new ArrayList<>();
if (values.contains(1)) {
String s1 ="1";
thingsIWantToKeep.add(s1);
}
if (values.contains(2)) {
String s2 ="2";
thingsIWantToKeep.add(s2);
}
System.out.println(thingsIWantToKeep);
```

so if the list values has 1 in it, it should add the value 1 to thingsIWantToKeep but it just prints out blank even though the list value has 1 init.

Comment: what was wrong with the answers provided in your previous question?  In that code it made sense not to add it to the List if it did not meet the requirements

Comment: Create another `ArrayList` with the values you want to keep, then call [`ArrayList#retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) on the original list, passing in the other

Comment: If you are removing elements, its better to do it using an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`List#retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) will *"Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection"*

```
List<String> thingsIHave = new ArrayList<>(25);
//...
List<String> thingsIWantToKeep = new ArrayList<>(25);
for (int index = 1; index < 24; index++) {
    thingsIWantToKeep.add(Integer.toString(index));
}
thingsIHave.retainAll(thingsIWantToKeep);
```

Comment: hey one more question, I used                                                           
       ` if (thingsIHave.contains(1)){ 
    String s1 ="1";
    thingsIWantToKeep.add(s1);}`
the arraylist thingsIHave does have the value 1 but still thingsIWantToKeep arrylist doesn't get 1 added to it. Any idea why?

Comment: It's a bit hard with out of context code snippet to tell, based on what you're showing me, it should work, assuming that `thingsIHave.contains` returns `true` when you pass it `1`

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code. Could you have a look at it please

Answer (score 0):

Create ArrayList containing elements you want to remove and call `removeAll` method:

```
list.removeAll(listToRemove);
```